# Writing to a file using FILE* and fprintf in c++ won't work as expected

Tags: c++

Not to bother anyone, but i have ran into an issue with a class of mine, somehow when i write to a file with the `FILE*` and `fprintf()` function i don't get any text in my text file that i created, i have searched all over youtube and i don't know what i'm doing wrong, because my code is the same.

Heres a copy of my .c++ and .h code:

main.c++:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "../include/include.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    write_file wf("test.txt");
    wf.write_line("Hello, world!");

    return 0;
}
```

include.h:

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_H
#define INCLUDE_H

#include <iostream>

class write_file {
public:
    write_file(const char *file_name) {
        FILE* fp = fopen(file_name, "w");
    }
    void write_line(const char *line) {
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", line);
    }
    void close() {
        fclose(fp);
    }
    private: FILE* fp;
};

#endif /* include.h */
```

Comment: `FILE* fp = fopen(file_name, "w");` in the constructor declares and initializes a local variable named `fp`, which is destroyed at the end of the function. The data member named `fp` remains uninitialized. `write_line` then exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing this uninitialized data member.

Comment: Even after fixing that, you are leaking the `FILE*` since you are never `fclose()`'ing it. You should call your `close()` method in your class destructor. Also: "*i have searched all over youtube and i don't know what i'm doing wrong*" - you are using YouTube to learn C++, which is not a good option.  Seriously, get yourself a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) instead.

Comment: You should `#include <cstdio>` instead of `<iostream>` if you want to use C streams

Comment: You should use C++'s `std::ofstream` class instead of C's `FILE` struct.

Comment: You should also read [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) so that you don't get in trouble later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Main issue:**

To fix your issue, you have to remove the local `fp` variable that shadows the class member.

When the compiler sees `FILE *fp` in your method, it uses a separate variable and is not referring to the one in your class instance.

Change the method definition to:

```
    write_file(const char *file_name) {
        fp = fopen(file_name, "w");
    }
```

**Additional points I really ought to comment on:**

- You never call `close`. Mishandling resources is one of the most common mistakes in C & CPP. Make sure to implement a destructor that calls `close`. If you do that, make sure to improve the `close` implementation to handle multiple calls.
- Consider using standard CPP classes for interacting with files, specifically `ifstream` and `ofstream`. Those handle a lot of the fuss automagically for you.
- Please don't use `.c++` as a file extension. This is really odd. Most CPP developers use `.cpp` or `.cc` for CPP source files.
- I might be saying that because I'm not a gen-Z kid, but please don't search Youtube for programming tutorials. Searching text-based sources is so much more efficient. Learn how to use [cplusplus](https://cplusplus.com) or [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises because your `FILE*` file handle that you declare inside the class constructor goes out of scope once program execution exits the constructor  (and also when you have just opened the file, ironically).

To avoid this , remove the FILE* declaration part in

```
FILE* fp = fopen(file_name, "w");
```

and use the `fp` data member you have in your class as

```
this->fp = fopen(file_name, "w");
```

You can also go on and remove the this-> if it hinders readability.
As mentioned in the other answer you have not provided a `fclose()` on the file that you just opened. This can lead to several worse problems than being unable to read files that I don't wish to expand upon now but which you can read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175827/what-happens-if-i-dont-call-fclose-in-a-c-program) .

Considering your class and use case where you are reading the file separately after opening it in constructor it's best to add `fclose()` in your class destructor like this.

```
~write_file() {
    fclose(this->fp);
}
```